# Simple sql Insertion failure?

Tags: php, html, sql, database

I've been trying to insert a tuple into my relation, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<?php

 $link=mysql_connect ("connection", "name", "pw");

 mysql_select_db('pizzaria');

 $sql = "INSERT INTO pizza_bakery (Name, Address, Telenum) 
 VALUES ('Test', 'Test', '111')";

 ?>
```

[image: relation]

The connection seems to go through ok, as I'm able to print the table out easily on my html page, why is this failing?

Comment: you are writing it as a string. change `'111'` to `111`

Comment: show more code. where your `mysql_query` function?

Comment: and I strongly recommend you to use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` coz `mysql_*` is deprecated

Comment: The reason is that the last line in your code only stores the sql code into a variable called $sql, but does not actually run it. To run it, you should use mysql_query: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php - though as previously said, mysql_* functions are deprecated and you should start using PDO instead so that the code you write now will still work for future PHP versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your insert statement should look something like this:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO pizza_bakery (Name, Address, Telenum) 
VALUES ('Test', 'Test', 111)";
```

**Reason**: The last column (Telenum) is an integer datatype and the insert statement was treating it like a string.

Comment: Hi @user1546716 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.